# Use Route53 / AWS Geolocation to hit different endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an API running on Elastic Beanstalk. The API has endpoints that will do different things depending on the location of the user requesting it.

I see that Route53 has a geolocation feature, and my understanding is that it can route to different EC2 instances based on location.

My case is that I have one EC2 instance running my API, and I want to route to different endpoints (or even could pass the location as an argument) according to the location.

Can I use Route53 to do that? If not, is there another way to do that for an API running in Elastic Beanstalk like I have?

For what its worth, the API is a Flask Python API..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Route53 feature really isn't intended to be used like you are describing. It won't route a request to a different *path* on a server based on the location, it simply routes all requests to a completely different server (usually in a completely different country) based on location.

What I would do is place CloudFront in front of your API, and use one of the [CloudFront location headers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/adding-cloudfront-headers.html), like  `CloudFront-Viewer-Country`, `CloudFront-Viewer-Country-Region` or even the Latitude/Longitude request headers that CloudFront adds to the requests it proxies to your API.

From there you could have a single API endpoint that checks that header and then calls different code execution paths in your backend code based on the location.

Comment: One follow-up, do you know if, without using Cloudfront, the IP address of the requester would be visible to the API running in EB? Or would Elastic Beanstalk obfuscate the request and it would appear to the API that the request is coming from within AWS

Comment: EB does not obfuscate anything about the requester. The requester's IP address will in the request. If you have a load balancer enabled on your Elastic Beanstalk deployment, then the requester's IP address will be in the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header.